# proof that $\{\rightarrow, \land \}$ is not a complete set of logical connectives

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need some help to prove that the set $\{\rightarrow, \land  \}$ of logical connectives is not a complete set.

can someone help me to understand what should I do?

thanks!

Comment: How would you get "not A" with just those two?

Comment: what do you mean in A?

Comment: sorry the TeX did not work the way I expected! Edited.

Comment: I think you can not get "not A" but I don't know how to prove it. I saw that it should be wuth induction somehow,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Prove by induction on the complexity of all well formed propositional expressions $\phi$ that only contain $\rightarrow, \wedge$ as connective symbols that $\phi^* \equiv \text{true}$, where $\phi^*$ results from $\phi$ by assigning $\text{true}$ to each variable in $\phi$. Since $\neg \text{true} \equiv \text{false}$, this implies that $\{ \rightarrow, \wedge \}$ is not a complete set of logical connectives.